# My @font-face doesn't work in Firefox, I cant find the issue, anything helps

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, font-face

The issue with the code below is that it works with Google Chrome And Internet Explorer, but when I load it up in Firefox the custom font doesn't load with it. Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

```
@font-face{
font-family:"Anxiolytic";
src:
url("../Fonts/Anxiolytic_Regular.eot?") format("eot"),
url("../Fonts/Anxiolytic_Regular.woff") format("woff"),
url("../Fonts/Anxiolytic_Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("../Fonts/Anxiolytic_Regular.svg#Anxiolytic") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Here is the picture of the different file types I downloaded for the Custom Font.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle

Comment: Is your `Fonts` directory also capitalized on the server?

Comment: make sure all the web fonts in  your folder and your showed path is right

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your stylesheet is in the same directory as your fonts. Change it to this:

```
@font-face{
font-family:"Anxiolytic";
src:
url("Anxiolytic_Regular.eot?") format("eot"),
url("Anxiolytic_Regular.woff") format("woff"),
url("Anxiolytic_Regular.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("Anxiolytic_Regular.svg#Anxiolytic") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```